# Create a simple proxy for browsers

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, .net, winapi

I want to create a simple proxy to get information that is sent by my browser and that is received by it. Searching, I've found that I probably need to use `Windows Filtering Platform` or `Layered Service Provide` (or is the former the base of the latter?). Also mentioned: `WinINET`  by Fiddler's creator [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1021992/939213). However, I'm having a difficult time selecting the current from the outdated methods. It also seems that I'll have to use pinvoke because there's no .net wrapper for this stuff (Hence the C++ tag). Is this still true?

So - What is the current best way about it, and where do I start? Any pointer may help - a WinAPI method, C# class (Fiddler is written in C#), ... (But no 3rd party software.)

Comment: FiddlerCore... I'm not sure how "simple proxy" is related to lower level network sniffers - you only need basic HTTP server for HTTP proxy (which can be written without any interop). Can you please clarify what "simple proxy" means for you?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov For the moment (until I know a little more about this) I just want to log what is sent each way.

Comment: I guess you'd have to get "know little more about this" first :). You need to figure out if you are trying to build simplified version of [NetMon](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865)/WhireShark level tool (generic network sniffer) or [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/)(straight HTTP proxy). In later case writing proxy and automatically configuring it (which is what your linked question refer to) are unrelated activities - you need to decide what exactly this question is about.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Well, the "know little more about this" is what I'm trying to achieve right now :) So for the latter - I'm trying now `HttpListener` (and getting an `access is denied` error at the moment) I hope I'm not wasting my time on the wrong technology.

Comment: @ispiro: What we're trying to say is, you need to understand _what_ you need. SO probably can tell you _how_.