# Listen to Browser's requests

Tags: c#, .net, http, httplistener

Using the following code:

```
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
//listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:80/");
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:8080/");
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:8081/");
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:8082/");
listener.Start();
HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
```

The program hangs on the `GetContext();` despite loading http (not https) pages in IE and Firefox.

When I uncomment the first line I get the error:

> Failed to listen on prefix 'http://*:80/' because it conflicts with an
>   existing registration on the machine.

So how do I listen to a browser's requests?

Comment: Are you running another web server… or Skype?

Comment: @minitech Nothing. Simple Windows 7 and no web stuff. (Visual Studio is running, of course.)

Comment: You need a proxy, http://fiddler2.com/ , http://fiddler2.com/fiddlercore

Comment: What is the URL you entered in the browser? HttpListener doesn't intercept requests to other sites, it just handles the requests directed to it.

Comment: are you running anything on your machine on port 80? Can you telnet to port 80?

Comment: @L.B I want to _write_ a "proxy". But all of my previous questions today have met with responses telling me to start with the basics. So that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @AllanElder Nothing. I don't have much experience with web developing, and am not running anything special. An anti-virus - yes. But that doesn't stop the browsers, so shouldn't be a problem. Right?

Comment: @minitech iis was listening on port 80. Stopped it and it runs. But still hangs on `HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();`.

Comment: @AllanElder See my previous comment.

Answer (score 5):

> @L.B I want to write a "proxy"

Don't reinvent the wheel and just use the [FiddlerCore](http://fiddler2.com/fiddlercore)

```
public class HttpProxy : IDisposable
{
    public HttpProxy()
    {
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest += FiddlerApplication_BeforeRequest;
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(8764, true, true);
    }

    void FiddlerApplication_BeforeRequest(Fiddler.Session oSession)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("REQ: {0}", oSession.url));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You can start with this rectangular wheel :)

```
void SniffPort80()
{
    byte[] input = new byte[] { 1 };
    Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
    socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 80));
    socket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, input, null);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[0x10000];

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int len = socket.Receive(buffer);
                if (len <= 40) continue; //Poor man's check for TCP payload
                string bin = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, len); //Don't trust to this line. Encoding may be different :) even it can contain binary data like images, videos etc.
                Console.WriteLine(bin);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Nope. I need to write it myself. That's the point of the question.

Comment: I started this because of the comments on my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027462/create-a-simple-proxy-for-browsers and that came after my first question on the subject http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021715/create-browser-vpn . I wish someone would just point me in the right direction instead of me wasting so much time...

Comment: So where do I start? `TcpClient`? All I want at the moment is to get the url that the browser is sending by listening to its traffic. I don't even care if that means that the request will then fail. _Anything._.

Comment: @ispiro: it sounds like you need to start way at the beginning, by understanding TCP/IP. I suggest you start with `TcpClient` and understanding some simple sample applications using it. Writing a proxy is far beyond where you currently are.

Comment: @ispiro I can post a code that reads all data of port 80 but these will be raw bytes of **all** tcp/http sessions. You will have to demultiplex them. I don't think it is a simple process (will require deep understanding of TCP and HTTP(s))

Comment: @L.B That would be a beginning at least. If there is only one instance of Firefox with one tab open - maybe it'll get me somewhere.

Comment: Square wheels are fine, don't be so spoiled :) Anyway - your code hangs on `int len = socket.Receive(buffer);`. I tried taking the `while...` out of the Task but it still hangs.

Comment: @ispiro you need to run it as `admin`. I works for me.

Comment: I _am_ running this as admin. Hmmmmmmmm.

Comment: I'm using a Winforms application and using `Debug.Write(bin);` instead of `Console.WriteLine(bin);` Would that make a difference?

Comment: @ispiro no. it works fine too. (I am also testing it in Winforms app)

Comment: @ispiro Just a hint: Go project/properties/Application and change the output type to Console Application. Now you have a console window that, I think, is easier to use for debug.

Comment: Thanks. (though it's now a textbox). But no go. I have no idea why. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @ispiro you can't use winform's controls. (unless you use invoke, await ... etc.)

Comment: I took it out of the "Task" and set a breakpoint on the `if (len <=...`.

Answer (score 1):

this port is probably being used...
run netstat -ano on the command line, youll see list of the ports that are being used and the their process ids.

Comment: I checked `Resource Monitor - Listening Ports` and there's nothing.

Comment: OK. I checked as you said and using the PID and "Process Explorer" - it's Firefox. But that's exactly my point - I need the port Firefox is using to listen to it.

Comment: try killing the process, run your code and then start firefox again

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't help.

Comment: I've found that iis was listening on it. So now it runs with `80`. But still hangs on `HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();`.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know, why the `GetContext();` hangs, because there is too less information about what happens with the listerner variable, but the problem with port 80 usually is caused by Skype, because it uses port 80 by default. To fix that, open Skype's preferences, go to advanced->connection and uncheck "Use Port 80 and 443 as an alternative for incoming Connections".

Comment: minitech was the only person that mentioned "skype". The OP said he did not have it.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider looking into this package http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost/
It uses HttpListener under the covers and with the WebApi HttpMessageHandler it is very easy to create a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

It hangs because GetContext() is waiting for a request to be received, as said in its documentation:

> This method blocks while waiting for an incoming request. If you want incoming requests to be processed asynchronously (on separate threads) so that your application does not block, use the BeginGetContext method.

For more info see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.getcontext(v=vs.110).aspx

Using Asynchronous model tends to be complex, another alternative is running all that code in a different Thread but it depends on your goals.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `*` in your prefixes with `+`

```
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:8080/");
```